# MongoDB - can not get a covered query

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I have an empty database 'tests' and a collection named 'test'.
First I ensured that my index was set correctly.

```js
db.test.ensureIndex({t:1})
db.test.getIndices()

[

    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "tests.test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "t" : 1
        },
        "name" : "t_1",
        "ns" : "tests.test"
    }
]
```

After that I inserted some test records.

```js
db.test.insert({t:1234})
db.test.insert({t:5678})
```

When I query the DB with following command and let Mongo explain the results I get the following output:

```js
db.test.find({t:1234},{_id:0}).explain()

{

    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "t" : [
            [
                1234,
                1234
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "XXXXXX:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me why indexOnly is false?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a [**covered index query**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries) you need to only retrieve those fields that are in the index:

```js
> db.test.find({ t: 1234 },{ _id: 0, t: 1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "t" : [
                    [
                            1234,
                            1234
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Essentially this means that **only** the index is used in order to retrieve the data, without the need to go back to the actual document and retrieve further information. This can be as many fields as you need ( within reason ), but they do need to be included within the index and the only fields that are returned.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that within the projection of the returned values I do not have to especially say {t:1}, because I only got 't' returned with my query from above without enabling t,

Comment: @aQuip The main thing being done here is removing the `_id` field which would not be contained in the index.

Comment: Haven't I done this with this Query `db.test.find({t:1234},{_id:0}).explain()`?

Comment: @aQuip Tecnically speaking that would imply all other fields but not `_id`. So even if the only other field is `t` the optimizer does not actually know this and presumes that is it not covered or "indexOnly" as you have not explicitly named all fields contained in the index.

Comment: @NeilOkay I think I got it. Thanks for your fast help.

Comment: So i have no tried this on another example. But now i get this error.
`error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.",
 "code" : 17287
}`

Comment: @aQuip Not a good place to add additional information in comments. If you have another question please feel free to post another question with all of your details. But the only field you can exclude is `_id` when including other fields. That is what that means.

Comment: @aQuip I'm showing you a covered index query in the answer, so the `"indexOnly": true` part in there. You seem to be trying to do something that is different from the question you actually asked, that is never a good idea. If you have another question to ask then please post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the reason has not been clearly explained (confusing me actually) so here is my effort.

Essentially in order for MongoDB to know that said index covers the query it has to know what fields you want.

If you just say you don't want `_id` how can it know that `*` - `_id` = `t` without looking?

Here `*` represents all fields, like it does in SQL.

Answer is it cannot. That is why you need to provide the full field/select/projection/whatever word they use for it definition so that MongoDB can know that your return fits the index.

Comment: Sure "Answer is it cannot." and a load of rhetoric that is not helpful. You didn't answer the question. This is nothing more than an extended comment. There was an answer. Not clear you say? Yet actually provides a working example and also takes the time to explain further to the new user who doesn't understand the issue. And all you have to say in the face of this is. "Why the downvote?". Since you cannot endorse "correct and helpful" I'm telling you why people would down-vote.

Comment: @NeilLunn I said that in response to the above two paragraph statements, which when read as a group do provide an answer, MongoDB cannot know that `{_id:0}` and `{_id:0,t:1}` (since `t` is the only field in the document) are the same without looking as your own answer proves. It might be an extended comment but it seems to me that your answer doesn't go quite far enough to actually state that. Your answer states a solution but it seems that it doesn't actually state *why* it is happening. If there is some information in my answer that is wrong then please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @NeilLunn it should also be not that the question is "Can anyone please explain to me why indexOnly is false?" which seems as though my answer does help

Comment: You didn't explain. I explained, and I explained your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn you explained that the fields need to be put into projection but you do not state exactly why MongoDB cannot know that `{_id:0}` and `{_id:0,t:1}` are the same in a document of `[_id,t]` using only an index, as I now see, it comes until the 4th comment on your answer when you explain it and the OP understands why and marks your answer after saying thanks. It wasn't until you said a briefer version of what I did above that the OP was satisfied.